# Cycles consistently dropping the same single object from render randomly

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I made a animation of about 750 frames, and every time I render the sequence (tried a quick version with 500x500px/200 max sample and 1080x1080/1024 max sample) it drops a object from the render at times.

I attached screenshots of the renders..every time a different frame is affected, but always about 2 or 3 in a stretch of 100 frames.

The object that is dissappearing is a BezierCurve with a Bevel geometry object attached to it, I attached a screenshot of the curve setup. I've stripped the scene down to as little as possible while still seeing the missing frames, I attached the blendfile. You can reproduce the effect yourself (might take more than 1 try, just render the first 80 frames or so).

So is this a bug right?

https://pasteall.org/blend/2b47aa256e6f4043b7b5447f4ad50cf8

[image: frame64]

[image: frame65]

[image]

One addition: also, sometimes it will not render the full amount of light effect/reflections on the surface. See below, where the left part is a single frame and the right part are all frames before and after it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve object "Roadshape" which you used to create the geometry for the street curve has *Path Animation* enabled. Disable it and right-click on the *Evaluation Time* value and choose *Clear Keyframes*. Then the problem should be gone.

**//EDIT:** This didn't seem to be the solution. Now I noticed that there is also a keyframed animation on the street curve object. The *Path Animation* option is already disabled, but additionally I cleared the keyframes on the *Evaluation Time* there as well.

I've now rendered the animation another ten times and didn't experience any errors anymore. I could only guess that there might have been some conflicts caused by the keyframing which get resolved randomly different during rendering.

Another workaround: if the street is not the curve which the car uses for its *Follow Path* constraint, you could also convert it to a mesh and use that for rendering.

[image: path animation]

Comment: Doesn't change anything..you can try yourself in the uploaded test blend file. also, if this setting was affecting the scene in any way, I would have expected the effect to be consistent on certain frames.

Comment: @Oli Well, I tried myself and it worked for me... (what did you think on which file I found that?) Sorry if this wasn't the answer for you. The only thing I noticed, it's not enough do disable _Path Animation_, I had to clear the keyframes on _Evaluation Time_ as well.

Comment: @Oli What you just added: this lighting effect for example still happened when I didn't clear the keyframes. //EDIT: Okay, seems like it's still not working for me either. But before this "solution" I experienced problems each time I rendered, now I just got a problem after rendering it a dozen times or so.

Comment: A dozen times? Wow, I get the disappearing road pretty much every time I render the animation..although the missing light is much rarer. i'll install the lastest stable build from today, and also 2.8 instead of 3.1, see if there's a difference

Comment: A dozen times after changing it, before it was almost each time as well. Strange things happening there...

Comment: I think it might be related to the performance -> final render -> persistent data option. When turning it off, I've had no issues so far.

Comment: @Oli I've edited my answer again. Maybe this is the solution. Maybe the persistent data option... I don't know, the problem is if I have to render it over and over again to see if the error reappears this can become very time consuming...

Comment: Thanks, the keyframing change seems to help..I'll have to be mindful about these settings in the future! edit: o lol no its back again. Well I'll do some more debugging with these paths and maybe convert the mesh..and perhaps file a bug report if this keeps up.

Comment: Tricky... anyway, it is always best to remove keyframes etc. if they are not used for anything, at least to make sure that they are definitely not to blame for strange behaviour.